# Curious behaviour with anonymous functions in Octave and MATLAB

Tags: matlab, octave

Hi I am curious why I am getting the following behaviour with MATLAB and Octave

```
octave:7> pdf = @(x) (0<=x && x<1).* (x) + (1<=x && x <=2).* (2-x);  
octave:8> 
octave:8> t = 0:0.1:1;
octave:9> 
octave:9> y = pdf(t)
y =

   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

octave:10>
```

I get the same behavior with MATLAB i.e. y is a zero vector.

But if I add  the following for loop

```
for i=1:size(t,1) 
  y(i) = pdf(t(i))
end
```

then I get the correct result.

```
 Columns 1 through 19:

 0.00000   0.10000   0.20000   0.30000   0.40000   0.50000   0.60000   0.70000   0.80000   0.90000   1.00000   0.90000   0.80000   0.70000   0.60000   0.50000   0.40000   0.30000   0.20000

 Columns 20 and 21:

   0.10000   0.00000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `&&` and `||` are the short circuit operators, meant for use with scalars.  Replace with `&` or `|`.  I get an error when executing the above (vectorized) code in Matlab (R2011B).

After replacing the `&&` with `&` it seems to work as you expect.